# Building list of dicts with map and lambda runs very slow

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm writing out an xlsx with XlsxWriter and the sheet includes a table.
For creating the table, you have to supply a list of dicts (ref : Eg. 7 : https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_tables.html#ex-tables )

I have the header names in a list, and now, to build the list of dicts for the add_table function, I use

```
headers = list( map( lambda x : { 'header' : x } , cols ) )
```

This one does not seem to scale well - with 18000 entries, it takes on the order of 10 minutes.

Any insight/improvement would be super. Thanks!

Comment: one first thing is move the lambda to a first class function, does that help significantly?

Comment: otherwise, I would do this with zip and comprehensions, rather than `map`, I find it confusing.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your suggestions. I'm functional with python, but not an expert by any means. Thanks!

Comment: [dict(x) for x in zip(["header",]*len(cols),cols)] ... maybe

Comment: try and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Specifically the complete part, just not with the 18 thousand records, but some example.

Comment: If we could see a small portion of the data you're trying to write in a [mcve] then I have a feeling this could be given an answer very quickly but, as it stands, I'm trying to imagine what you're doing from a function, and the 10 min run time means that something has gone catastrophically wrong (I'd expect maybe a couple of seconds _maximum_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create object like:

```
[{'header': 'A'},
 {'header': 'B'},
 {'header': 'C'}]
```

From

```
names = ["A","B","C"]
```

You can use list comprehension:

```
[{"header": x} for x in names]
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. This just writes a list of column headers and no data at all.

Comment: The dictionaries should contain the values that _belong under each header_, not a list of dictionaries stating the header name

Comment: This works - went from minutes to less than a second :) I suck at python obviously :)   Really appreciate everyone chipping in so soon. Thanks Konrad.

Comment: FYI, on the [dict(x) for x in...]  I got : ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required

Comment: @roganjosh in the examples in docs there is one with this type of initialization of column names and data goes as separate arg.

Comment: You will have to show me the specific example. I'm pretty certain this answer does not address what the OP is trying to do; the list of dictionaries should contain k, v pairs where the `k` is the column name and `v` is the data to be written to that column. The output of your example code would not give a useful file.

Comment: Example 7 in link of the question

Comment: Sorry to have unintentionally misled everyone - looks like the map/lambda version also runs fast. So, I really don't know what's going on. The same case sometimes runs fast, and sometimes not. That being said, the list comprehension version is more readable than what I originally had, so I do appreciate that..